# How to do foreach in Meteor with Mongo?

Tags: meteor

Have collection

```
 Peoples = new Mongo.Collection('peoples');

    Peoples.insert({
        name: ["Mark", "John", "Kate"]
    });
```

I want to show all names in **name**

```
<template name="pTable">
  <tr class="trJob">
    <td>
      {{#each names}}
          {{> peopleName}}
      {{/each}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<template name="peopleName">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

What in my Temlate helpers

```
Template.pTable.helpers({
  names: function(){
    return Posts.tags;
  }
});

Template.peopleName.helpers({
  name: function(){
    return Posts.tags.find();
  }
});
```

I know that i have sh*** code in my Template helpers, any idea how to make it good ?

It must look like (in DOM)

```
<td>
  <div>Mark</div>
  <div>John</div>
  <div>Kate</div>
</td>
```

Comment: do you want to go over all the people or just one person? or posts?

Comment: @ZeevG i want to make in <td> 3 div's , in one div 1 name.
Soo in DOM it must look like this
td 
  div Mark
  div John
  div Kate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple array example

```
Template.home.helpers({
  names: function(){
    return [1,2,3];
  }
});

<template name="home">
      {{#each names}}
        {{this}}
      {{/each}}
</template>
```

will print:

1 2 3

each item becomes "this" inside the each loop. if you call another template within the loop, then its "this" will be populated by the item

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282522/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-array-of-strings-with-the-meteor-spacebars-each-bl

Answer (score 1):

Since you have different names for your collection, I will stick with the first one `Peoples`

Here is how I would proceed with your helpers:

```
Template.pTable.helpers({
  names: function(){
    return People.find({_id:yourId},{fields:{name:1}}).fetch();
  }
});
```

And your `peopleName` template would be like this:

```
<template name="peopleName">
    <div>{{this}}</div>
</template>
```

If you need to get all the names of all your documents, I need to nest your `{{#each names}}` into another `{{#each doc}}` where `doc` helper is like this (updated `names` as well) :

```
Template.pTable.helpers({
     doc: function(){
        return People.find().fetch();
      },
    names: function(){
            return People.find({_id:this.id},{fields:{name:1}}).fetch();
    });
```

Comment: I updated it to add `.fetch()` after the `Collection.find()`. It returns now an array of document instead of a cursor. It should work now.